# How to use eager loading relation with compare in Yii framework 2 ActiveRecord?

Tags: yii2, eager-loading, relation

I have a "comment" table. I need to get a record of the next comment for each comment.

```
public function getNext()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(self::class, [
            'bd_name' => 'bd_name',
            'uid_client' => 'uid_client',
            'remind_uid_user' => 'remind_uid_user',
        ])
            ->andOnCondition(['or',
                [">", 'dt_remind', $this->dt_remind],
                ['and', ["=", 'dt_remind', $this->dt_remind], [">", 'tm_remind', $this->tm_remind]]
            ])
            ->orderBy(['dt_remind' => SORT_ASC, 'tm_remind' => SORT_ASC]);
    }
```

This needs to be done with eager loading, as there can be a lot of records.

```
$actions['index']['modifyQuery'] = function(CommentQuery $query) {
    $query->with(['next']);
};
```

But when I use "with", "andOnCondition" takes the "dt_remind/tm_remind" only from the first record in the selection.

```
AND (("dt_remind" > '2019-06-17') OR (("dt_remind" = '2019-06-17') AND ("tm_remind" > '14:39:34')))
```

Comment: You can't use `$this->attribute` in relation definition, if you want to use this relation with joins or eager loading. There is no simple and efficient way to build SQL query to fetch such relation for multiple records at once (and it is completely impossible for joins). You need to build `ON` condition using columns relation, like `t.dt_remind < next.dt_remind`.

Comment: Why not make a `hasMany` relation that would contain all coments with later date/time and that would be ordered by date/time? Then, when you iterate through results of that relation for current item the next item in array will be the "next comment".

Comment: @MichalHynčica I do not understand from what date/time to start counting. If use a sort other than date/time and use the code I showed above for `hasOne`, then will get the wrong set of `hasMany` items.

Comment: @rob006 I also don’t understand how to use the column relations, since the onCondition requires you to use specific values.